# redirect with .htaccess old url to the new url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, rule

Hell guys, can someone help me with a .htaccess rule to redirect such url type:

old url: `video/displayresults/?pattern=searchedword`

new url: `video/search/?searchword=searchedword`

So i want to redirect any old url to the new url

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to look up htaccess `RewriteRule` directive. You'll need to construct the regular expression that that it captures "/displayresults/?" and parses it into "/search/". Ensure that you have mod_rewrite enabled

Example:

> RewriteRule ^(.*)/displayresults/(.*)$ $1/search/$2

This assumes displayresults is a folder name.

Comment: I`ve found for now this:<br/> `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pattern=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) /video/search/?searchword=%1 [L,R=301]` but i want to make it just for urls which have /video/displayresullts/ on them

Answer (score 0):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` (if not already enabled) and then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pattern=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(video)/displayresults/?$ /$1/search/?searchword=%1 [L,NC,R=301]
```